# Annotate class with inner class

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I create my **enums** through **reflection**, for that I add to each enum an inner class which implements the **abstract factory**. Now I want to access this inner class in order to invoke the method:

```
@Factory(FooFactory.class)
public enum Foo {

     FOO, BAR;

     public class FooFactory implements AbstractFactory<Foo> {

          public Foo create(String value) {
               return valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
          }
     }
}
```

The definition of `@Factory` is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Factory {

        Class<?> value();
}
```

With this, however, I receive the following **error**:

> Class cannot be resolved to a type FooFactory.java

When I try `@Factory(Foo$FooFactory.class)` I receive the **error**:

> The nested Foo$FooFactory cannot be referneced using its binary name.

So is it even possible to reference a nested class?

Comment: I suspect FooFactory needs to be `public static class`.

Comment: @Charlie I tried that already.

Comment: enums are usually for fixed, known values. This seems kind of odd.

Comment: Did you try `@Factory(Foo.FooFactory.class)` ?

Comment: Vivin has a good point, why a reflexive factory when you can do `Enum.valueOf(Foo.class,value.toUpperCase())` ?

Comment: @Charlie Because this is just an example I have factory methods which are more complex and individual per enum.

Comment: When do you get the error? At compile time? Also what version of Java?

Comment: @Charlie Yes at compile time. Charlie your second suggestion did in fact work separating the inner and outer class with a dot is the solution. If you want you can answer the question and I accept it since you suggested it first.

Comment: Interesting... I was able to get it to compile fine in Eclipse without the qualification... but if you're up and going great :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the comments... apparently

```
@Factory(Foo.FooFactory.class)
```

was needed.

Answer (score 4):

You're using a non-static nested class, which is scoped to the individual instances of the enum.

Instead, you need a static nested class, like so:

```
public static class FooFactory implements AbstractFactory<Foo> {

      public static Foo create(String value) {
           return valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
      }
 }
```

However, all of this is redundant: you can simply call `Foo.valueOf(value)` to achieve this goal. I don't see any value added here (no pun intended).

Factory.java

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Factory {
        Class<?> value();
}
```

FooEnum.java

```
@Factory(FooEnum.FooFactory.class)
public enum FooEnum {
    FOO, BAR;
    public static class FooFactory  {

          public static FooEnum create(String value) {
               return valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
          }
     }
}
```

FooEnumMain.java

```
public class FooEnumMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooEnum f = FooEnum.FooFactory.create("foo");
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you have something else going on that you're not telling us about.. I was able to get your setup to work. I'll edit in code samples.

Comment: It does indeed work, but it has nothing to do with the `static` modifier.

Answer (score 3):

At the point when your annotation is presented, FooFactory is undefined, so the full path needs to be specified:

```
@Factory(Foo.FooFactory.class)
```